# Language C: basic question regarding calculator function in EdX program

Tags: c, makefile, calculator, cs50

Question; I'm brand new to coding and doing the self taught route; not important. But building the calculator in cs50.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = get_int ("x: ");
    int y = get_int("y: ");
    printf("%i\n", x + y);
}
```

Is the base set; when I go into my terminal to $ make calculator there's an output of...

make: *** No rule to make target 'calculator'. Stop.

I feel as though I'm missing something very basic here; for what its worth I have the terminal set to the wsl so I can route Ubuntu through this from a previous coding bootcamp suggestion; unsure if this is making things weird..?

Comment: This is not a C question but rather a Makefile question. Please show the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

> make: *** No rule to make target 'calculator'. Stop.

means that there is a line missing in your makefile. Hence here comes a complete example of everything.

Source in standard C without library `cs50`:

*calculator.c*

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// no cs50.h hence using a helper function
int get_int(char * msg) {int n; printf("%s", msg); scanf(" %d", &n); return n;}

int main(void)
{
    int x = get_int ("x: ");
    int y = get_int("y: ");
    printf("%i\n", x + y);
}
```

Simple makefile (the use of tabulators for indentation is required):

*Makefile*

```
default: calculator

calculator.o: calculator.c
    gcc -c calculator.c -o calculator.o

calculator: calculator.o
    gcc calculator.o -o calculator

clean:
    -rm -f calculator.o
    -rm -f calculator
```

And now let's see:

```
$ make calculator
gcc -c calculator.c -o calculator.o
cc   calculator.o   -o calculator
$ ./calculator 
x: 1
y: 1
2
$
```

Comment: @TheSicknessX Do you still have any issues or does this solve your question? If so, please accept the answer so that the question is marked as closed.